# append only new row or update previous record if doesn't exist using python

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-workbench

I have created the database and table in MySQL to load csv file in MySQL table using python script and it's working fine but when I add new row in existing csv file and then I execute python script then it will load all the data from starting till end and it create duplication in MySQL table I just want to append only new row or updated row will update in MySQL table otherwise existing record not be loaded. plz can anybody help me regarding this? below are the code I'm using.

```
    #create table under database and insert the records in MySQL server.

    try:

    conn = msql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', database='AuditLogDB',user='root', 
    password='Pharma123')

    if conn.is_connected():

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select database();")

    record = cursor.fetchone()
    print("You're connected to database: ", record)

    cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AuditLogs;')

    print('Creating table....')

    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE AuditLogs (Id nvarchar (50), CreationTime nvarchar (50),UserId nvarchar(50) ,Operation nvarchar(50) ,Workload nvarchar(50) ,DatasetName nvarchar(50),ReportName nvarchar(50) ,ReportId nvarchar(50) ,Activity nvarchar(50) ,ActivityId nvarchar(50) ,DatasetId nvarchar(50),LastRefreshTime nvarchar(50),ObjectId nvarchar(255),SiteUrl nvarchar(50),SourceFileName nvarchar(50),ClientIP nvarchar(50),UserAgent nvarchar(50),Email nvarchar(50))")

    print("AuditLogs table is created....")

    for i,row in AuditLogData.iterrows():
        sql = "INSERT INTO AuditLogDB.AuditLogs VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
       
      # the connection is not autocommitted by default, so we must commit to save our changes
        
       conn.commit()

       except Error as e:
       print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
```